# Get music tempo or BPM?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, fft

I'm currently building a game in windows phone 7 using xna
i'm trying to get beat per minute from song that played in background song,
i also not quite sure if what i want is BPM, what i want is something like pace or tempo in music, faster the pace ,faster the sprites is moving. What i'm thinking right now, BPM is how much a frequency from music hits a range of defined constant, e.g 20 Mhz - 30 MHz, 
Feel free to correct me if i'm wrong, i'm not really familiar with audio thing, i have tried using VisualizationData from MediaLibrary XNA, but after some googling they said that VisualizationData doesn't work with WP7, i also had tried it and the output is 256 length float array contains 0 value,,or if i could do some fft with it,i'll give it a try
Thank you...

Comment: What you want is BPM not frequency. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempo#Beats_per_minute

Comment: okay, so how can i compute that using xna? any idea??

Answer (score 3):

Like you were saying, as for the beats you can't get it directly but **you'll have to interpret this data**.  If you personally can preprocess this music and ship it with your title it would be your best bet

In XNA you really only have [MediaPlayer.GetVisualizationData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer.getvisualizationdata%28v=XNAGameStudio.40%29.aspx) to work with. There isn't anything built in that allows you to predetermine this sort of thing.  It's used like the following and gets you information about the different frequencies that are playing.

```
MediaPlayer.IsVisualizationEnabled = true;
VisualizationData visData = new VisualizationData();
MediaPlayer.GetVisualizationData(visData);
```

So how do you take this frequency stuff and make it worthwhile for your application? There's a great breakdown of how you can do this that's [on the App Hub forums in this thread called "Audio Analysis" in the reply by jwatte](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/27745/171877.aspx#171877).  Essentially, you're going to look at the low frequencies and try to figure out when the beats are coming in. Nothing perfect, but hopefully you'll get something that you approve of.

Good luck!

Comment: but VisualizationData doesn't work in Windows Phone right? currently i'm reading about AudioContent from Content.Pipeline but i still don't know how to use it, i can't get the reference that contains Microsoft.Xna.Content.Pipeline in my game reference, i had tried to add reference but i can't get it anywhere, i also had tried to using Content Library Extension but it comes with an warning about mscorlib version, i think i will try to reading .wav data, but i also found it hard to read from a file binary in XNA Windows Phone, Life is not that simple right? :p

Comment: I'm 99% sure it's in WP7. Did you enable visualization? I forgot to add that to the code sample. I'll update it.

Comment: igot that from msdn site.. Visualization data is not available on Windows Phone. Any attempt to get visualization data on the phone will populate the VisualizationData class with 0s. check this out : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer.getvisualizationdata.aspx